# not able to view data in html in angular7

Tags: angular

I am trying to fetch data from web service, I am using Observable for that, I am getting response from web API but result are not displaying on html.

following is my `services.ts`

```
getForeports(searchText: string): Observable<FoReport[]> {
   return this.http.get(Constant.API_URL + 'getFoReports.php?searchText=' + encodeURIComponent(searchText))
   .pipe(map(result=>result['data']))
 }
```

following is my `component.ts` code

```
import { FoReport } from '../../models/report';

reports: FoReport[] = [];

getDataUsingObservable() {
    this.reportservice.getForeports(this.filterText).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
            this.reports = response.statistics;
            console.log(this.reports);
        });
}
```

following is my API response

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {State: "Karnataka", SurveyorName: "Keval Kakdiya", NoOfInt: "2", SampleReceived: "2", CancelledEntries: "0", …}
1: {State: "MAHARASHTRA", SurveyorName: "Keval Kakdiya", NoOfInt: "0", SampleReceived: "0", CancelledEntries: "1", …}
```

following is my HTML code

Hide   Copy Code

```
<tr *ngFor="let report of reports">
    <td> {{report.name}}            </td>
    <td> {{report.formSubmited}}    </td>
    <td> {{report.formCancelld}}    </td>
    <td> {{report.formApproved}}    </td>
    <td> {{report.formDisApproved}} </td>
    <td> {{report.state}}</td>
    <td> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you share the API URL if it is public

Comment: this my api url         getForeports(index: number, size: number, search: string, searchText: string, orderBy: string = '', orderDir: string = 'ASC') {
        return this.http.get(Constant.API_URL + 'getFoReports.php?searchText=' + encodeURIComponent(searchText))
            .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
            console.log(encodeURIComponent(searchText));
    }

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you read the data correctly.

```
<td> {{report.State}}</td>
```

As you haven't post whole object.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your response keys are not matching with that of the ones you have used in your template. For example, you have `State` in your response where as you are using `state`

In order to check whether you have the response as needed in the template, try to lo it in the template as

```
{{ reports | json }}
```

and cross-check the properties you are using in your template.

Comment: after changing with State still, I am not getting results, and also not any kind of error in the console

Comment: any one here who help me on this

Comment: still i am not getting answer